# Properties of a middle resolution of a Horseshoe Lemma

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I understand the proof of Horseshoe lemma as it is presented in, e.g. Weibel's book. However both Weibel and [these](http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedFunctors.pdf) notes note an additional property which is at the bottom of my screenshots here:

[image]

[image]

This property is used in a crucial way in the proof that left derived functors form a homological $\delta$-functor in both said notes and Weibel's book. How does it follow from the Horseshoe Lemma?

Comment: Which property are you referring to specifically ? $P_n = P_n'\oplus P_n''$ or something else ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi The ones stated in the last paragraph: there is a morphism $\sigma\colon P''_0\to A$ such that $\epsilon = (\phi\circ\epsilon',\sigma)$ and morphisms $\lambda_n\colon P''_n\to P'_{n - 1}$ for $n \geq 1$ such that the differential is... These morphisms satisfy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite ashamed for asking this since the answer turnes out to be trivial, but I suppose if it's trivial, then why don't write it down.

First, in every additive category $\mathsf{A}$, every morphism between biproducts $f\colon A_1\oplus A_2 \to B_1\oplus B_2$ can be written uniquely in the following form:

$$f = \begin{bmatrix}f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

where $f_{ij}$ is the morphism $A_j\to B_i$ such that $$f_{ij} = \pi^B_i\circ \begin{bmatrix}f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{bmatrix} \circ l^A_j$$ where $\pi^B_i\colon B_1\oplus B_2 \to B_i$ are product projections and $l^A_j\colon A_j\to A_1\oplus A_2$ are coproduct injections.

Moreover, we have $\pi^A_i\circ l^A_j$ equal to $1_{A_i}$ if $i = j$ and to $0$ otherwise (and similarly for $B$).

Now consider the (commutative by the Horseshoe lemma) diagram:

[image]

and set

$$d_{n + 1} = \begin{bmatrix} f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

We compute, by the commutativity of the diagram:

$$f_{11} = \pi'_n\circ d_{n + 1}\circ l'_{n + 1} = \pi'_n\circ l'_n\circ d'_{n + 1} = d'_{n + 1},$$
$$f_{21} = \pi''_n\circ d_{n + 1} \circ l'_{n + 1} = d''_{n + 1}\circ \pi''_{n + 1}\circ l'_{n + 1} = d''_{n + 1}\circ 0 = 0,$$
$$f_{22} = \pi''_n\circ d_{n+1}\circ l''_{n + 1} = d''_{n + 1}\circ \pi''_{n + 1}\circ l''_{n + 1} = d''_{n + 1}.$$

Then $f_{12}$ is the desired morphism $\lambda_{n + 1}$.